# Is it possible to go Robinson Crusoe in the Bahamas?

Tags: extreme-tourism, bahamas

Given that the Bahamas consists of about 700 islands is it possible to go Robinson Crusoe on one of them?  I mean staying on one of the uninhabited ones away from the civilization.

Shipwreck is optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you call "going Robinson Crusoe". If it is about spending time alone on an uninhabited island, I guess the answer is "Sure". I have met various people who did so, when they were sailing through the Caribbean. The options to do so is not limited to the Bahamas alone. I was told that it is relatively cheap to buy a yacht in that area from European sailors who after crossing the atlantic don't feel the urge to experience yet again the gulf of Biscay. Those boats are typically quite worn out, which would add a bit to the Robinson Crusoe experience. So if it is only about being alone on a deserted island, just buy one of these boats and sail away.

If "going Robinson Crusoe", however means being lost for years, the fact that I have met various people who did spent time alone on an uninhabited island makes it impossible. Spending time on an island without being noticed by civilization for an extended period of time, is simply impossible given the number of people sailing the Caribbean. these days.

PS. Robinson crusoe was stranded: "Who lived Eight and Twenty Years, all alone in an un-inhabited Island on the Coast of America, near the Mouth of the Great River of Oroonoque".

The island is situated in front of the Guyana's. There are quite some small islands over there, of which [Devil's islands is the most famous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_Island). Even devil's island is not visible on [Google maps](https://maps.google.be/maps?q=devil%27s%20island&hnear=Devils%20Island&gl=be&t=m&z=11). I have the impression that your chances on getting lost unnoticed in that area is higher then in the Bahamas. "Devil's island is ofcourse not a good choice, but there are more of these small islands.

Comment: I have serious doubts that years alone are possible in the Bahamas....  Too close to civilization but a week or two will suffice.